# How to warp text around image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a custom table cell.On that table cell i want to display the **UIImage** wrapped with text  which will be fetched from server.I want my UI something like this.

[image]

I have got this code

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
self.textView.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect]
```

**EDIT:**

The above code will create a blank space area for image in the text view but how to fit the image in that area ?

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you have to create an UIImageView , set its origin the same as the textview and then adjust imgRect-s size depending on the size of the image,

Superview - // The superview of imageview and the textview

- UIImageView {0,0, 100, 100} // lets say 100x100 is the size of image
- UITextView {0,0, 300, 300} , exclusion - {0,0, 100, 100} // 300x300 is the size of textview , 100x100 is the size of the image , you can also have bigger exclusion size to have prettier spacing between the text and the image

There is also second solution, to create NSAttributedString and append NSTextAttachment in front of it, but while you are doing this, you have to already have the Image itself, so if you are fetching Image asynchronously, The first solution would be better.

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = img;
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
NSMutableAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
[attrStr appendAttributedString:attrStringWithImage];
```

Comment: size of image will be dynamic as well as the text size

Comment: You can fetch the size of image from the server ( you should already know it on the server, right ? ) , or after fetching the image , you can get its size from UIImage and then adjust the UIImageView-s frame and textviews- exclusion path , text size does not matter , you can have as large text as you want.

Comment: let me try your code just be there in case your code does not work or it just stuck

Comment: well i have added image view & textview from storyboard so which solution should be better.

Comment: try the first one, it should be more simple and it allows you to fetch image asynchronously

Comment: can you provide full code in that case ?Actually creating views at run time is very complex thing so i wanted to avoid it & have them from story borad. can you provide the source code for your first example

Comment: You can add UIImageView and the textview from storyboard, set IBoutlets and then change the size of them.

Comment: that will not wrap arround the text as i posted an image.See my image i want exactly that

Comment: Yes , and as I told , create UIImageView and the textview , then you can change their settings ( frame,exclusion path ) from the code.

Comment: That is the code i need.i don't know what to write & how.posted a code snippet that create a space before text but i don't know how to fit image in that area.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding the Imagview into the Texview as subview

```
UIBezierPath * imgRect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
cell.tv_post.textContainer.exclusionPaths = @[imgRect];
        UIImageView *tv_image =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 100, 100)];
[tv_image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[IMAGE_BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:user_post.post_video_thumbnail]]placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"post_placeholder.png"]];
[cell.tv_post addSubview:tv_image];
```