# Nativescript text around another text

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

How can I make text to be around other text or image? I need something like this:

```
Label1 Label1 Label2
Label1 Label1 Label1
...
```

Label1 is all around Label 2...

Here is what I tried:

```
<FlexboxLayout width="100%" row="1">
        <Label [text]="item.description" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <Label text="3.33" width="100" height="50" textWrap="true"></Label>
</FlexboxLayout>
```

But It not looking good...

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by text around text. If it's about placing labels one after another, it's quite straight forward. You have do `<FlexboxLayout flexWrap="wrap" alignContent="flex-start">`, here is [the Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=MKx2JY).

Comment: Basicly big text of first label to go below second which have 3 char

Comment: Might be easier to understand if you could update the Playground and share.

Comment: Check image: https://www.coffeecup.com/files/images/image_wrap_align.png Same as that but instead image I need Label(text with on word)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is supported out of the box yet, but if you are interested you could use the native solution for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33209439/how-to-warp-text-around-image-in-ios?rq=1) / [Android](https://github.com/deano2390/FlowTextView).